# Create button doesn't do anything on Add Connection dialog for a new SQL Server CE connection

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce

I have just deleted a SQL Server CE database, attempting to start a debugging process with a fresh, new database, but when I try to add a new CE connection using Server Explorer, the Create button simply does nothing.  What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server Compact tools are broken, re-install SSCEvstools.msi from the VS Installtion media